# I want to using phonegap print plugin on iPad

Tags: plugins, cordova, printing

I am developing webapp for iPad.

I want to use Phonegap print plugin.

But, iPad print plugin is not working.(on version 5.1)

(iPad version 4.3 or iPhone version 5.1 print plugin is working well)

how can I use Phonegap print plugin?

Comment: I need the same, my app has developed in sencha touch v1, The following link recommends using xcode, but I prefer to live alone and PhoneGap sencha touch http://tinyurl.com/7mprn8e